# Beamer uncovering a table columnwise

Tags: tables, beamer, animations

I want to uncover a table columnwise in `beamer`. I am doing the following thing:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{crrr<{\onslide<2->}r<{\onslide<2->}r<{\onslide<2->}r<{\onslide}}
    & $f_1$    & $f_2$ & $S$   & $f''_1$ & $f''_2$ & $T$\\
$A$ &   2\,000 & 500   & 100.0 & 100     & 100     & 100.0 \\
$B$ &   1\,120 & 175   & 45.5  & 70      & 35      & 52.5
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{crrr<{\onslide<2->}r<{\onslide<2->}r<{\onslide<2->}r<{\onslide}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$f_1$}   &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$f_2$}   &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S$}     &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$f''_1$} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$f''_2$} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$T$}     \\
$A$ &   2\,000 & 500  & 100.0 & 100   & 100   & 100.0 \\
$B$ &   1\,120 & 175  & 45.5  & 70    & 35    & 52.5
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

On the first frame everything works quite well.
On the second frame, I am adding `\multicolumn` and things get messy.
I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same technique as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2000#a2242

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={rrrrrrr},
            cells={cmd=\onslide<\arabic{colnum}->},
      row{1}={halign=c}
    }
                & $f_1$    & $f_2$ & $S$   & $f''_1$ & $f''_2$ & $T$\\
      $A$ &   2\,000 & 500   & 100.0 & 100     & 100     & 100.0 \\
      $B$ &   1\,120 & 175   & 45.5  & 70      & 35      & 52.5
        \end{tblr}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

or if instead of uncovering the columns one by one, you want to split the table in two parts:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}<4,7>
        \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={rrrrrrr},
            cells={cmd=\onslide<\arabic{colnum}->},
      row{1}={halign=c}
    }
                & $f_1$    & $f_2$ & $S$   & $f''_1$ & $f''_2$ & $T$\\
      $A$ &   2\,000 & 500   & 100.0 & 100     & 100     & 100.0 \\
      $B$ &   1\,120 & 175   & 45.5  & 70      & 35      & 52.5
        \end{tblr}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Spectacularly precise and useful answer

Comment: @Denis You're welcome!